# set default value in HTML with dynamic values in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to set default value of `e.name` to "**ALL**" using `ng-init`
Here is my **TEMPLATE** code :

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in employees" ng-init="employees[0] = 'ALL'">
   <td>{{ $index + 2}}</td>
   <td>{{ e.name}}</td>
   <button type="button" ng-click="select(employee)">
          Select
   </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**DIRECTIVE link**

```
scope.employees = EmployeeService.query();
```

Here I want to set default value of `e.name` to **ALL** before generating dynamic data
I am getting dynamic data properly in employees and `{{ e.name}}` from directive

but here I want to show **ALL** in same `<td>` before getting dynamic data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to *display* `ALL` before data is retrieved, you could consider using an [or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in employees">
   <td>{{$index + 2}}</td>
   <td>{{e.name || 'ALL'}}</td>
   <button type="button" ng-click="select(employee)">
          Select
   </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

However, if you actually need `ALL` to be a value, I would strongly suggest setting it to the default value where ever you model `employees`.

Comment: I am getting error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ''ALL'' is not a valid identifier at column 19 of the expression [e.name | 'ALL'] starting at ['ALL'].`

Comment: @ojuskulkarni Are you using two pipes? The error provided suggests that you are only using one. Please ensure you're using two pipes like the following: `{{e.name || 'ALL'}}`

Comment: Yes mistakenly I used single `|` pipe, but now I am using `||` it's good that I am not getting error but I it's not showing **ALL** at first position.
ok and I updated my question, added `$scope.employees` so now how I set default value there ?

Comment: Then it sounds like `e.name` is already defined. I see you've edited your post to include more details. What does `EmployeeService.query();` return by default?

Comment: It's giving all employee entries from database. and I am getting all entries properly here only the problem is before rendering all this dynamic entries I want to set default value so that when I don't want any employee entry that time it should be possible for me to select default value

Comment: Is `scope.employees` defined before invoking `EmployeeService.query();`?

Comment: No, `scope.employees` not defined before service.query.